# Cannot load multiple photospheres using google maps streetview API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load custom photospheres inside of map pin descriptions using the google maps streetview api.

It loads correctly the first time, but when I attempt to open either the same map pin or another, (which sets the panoimg variable and recalls initPano()), I get a blank image. And in the console, a failed 400 error to the URL https://geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client=apiv3&panoid=custom&output=tile&x=0&y=0&zoom=0&nbt&fover=2

I've got an my code here on JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/falldeaf/9ej8x2xj/1/
(JSfiddle stripped down further to **NOTHING** except the problem described)

I"m trying to call this function each time a map pin is opened:

```
   function initPano() {
        var panoOptions = {
          pano: 'custom',
          visible: true,
          panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
        };

        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
          document.getElementById('pano-canvas'), panoOptions);
      }

      function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
        console.log(panoimg);
        return "https://www.tcpalmextras.com/tcpalm_hosted/images/brandyhallmap/" + panoimg;
      }
```

You can see the error occur by clicking the map pin on the screen, then closing the popup, then **opening** it again. This second and all subsequent openings don't properly load the photosphere.

Comment: I don't see the problem described when I run [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/falldeaf/obf5df1w/2/). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site (like jsfiddle).

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by your comment. I clearly described the problem and how to reproduce it. The last line of my question should be clear. Click on a map marker, it will open and a photo sphere will be in it. Close the pop-up then try to open it once more. The photo sphere will not load that or any subsequent time. To be more clear, that  is not the full app, either. It's a stripped down example illustrating the problem.

Comment: It is clear, it doesn't happen for me.  I click on the marker, the photosphere opens.  I close it.  I click on the marker again.  The photosphere opens again.  Currently in IE11, earlier in Chrome. (I obviously don't see it if I "close the popup, then closing it again" (sic), which is what the last line of your question states)

Comment: I meant to say **opening** it again. My mistake.

I've tried this on multiple machines in Chrome and IE and they all perform the way they do in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iUrBwHGnYgJi8MCmBeWbgo1N4sU_L5y5/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating the custom photospheres inside of modal windows, do NOT add **visible:true** option present in the examples to the new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama object's options.

Removing that line allows them to open an indefinite number of times.